# Question regarding Lucet - A WebAssembly runtime

Tags: webassembly

Since I was working on WebAssembly runtime these days, and I have a question regarding the WebAssembly runtime Lucet. I've taken a look at the official document, and it says the Lucet runtime tool `lucetc` can compile .wat or .wasm file into a platform-dependent shared object file (.so/.o), so, what's the difference between this process and compiling the source C/C++ file directly into the same shared object file with Clang/GCC?

As the doc says (https://bytecodealliance.github.io/lucet/Your-first-Lucet-application.html), we need to compile the source C/C++ file into .wasm with Clang, and then compile the .wasm file into .so file with `lucetc`. Finally, run the generated .so file with `lucet-wasi`. So, why do we need to waste time here splitting the whole process into three? I can directly compile the source C/C++ file into .so with Clang/GCC, then run the result with `lucet-wasi`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Wasm is a compilation target. You can not only compile c++ to wasm, you can also compile rust, c#, golang, Kotlin and so on into wasm files. lucet is a native wasm compiler and runtime, it allows you to run wasm inside your application. it also provide features like hostcall to make wasm modules interact with your applications.

One great example of using Lucet is in the FaaS edge computing scenario. In this scenario, you can compile users code into wasm module and execute user's module in a safe and efficient way.